# Zabbix graphs : using a previous timeshift as a background

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, graph

I want to improve my zabbix graphs,

Something like desribed in this netflix article (about sps)

http://techblog.netflix.com/2015/02/sps-pulse-of-netflix-streaming.html

[image]

Show current data under the data of previous period.

It mean draw current day data over prev day data.

Is it possible?

If its impossible in zabbix, what I could use for that?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You have to create new calculated item, where do you use some function (avg) with  optional parameter time_shift (e.g 1 day). And then you will need to create graph with original item and calculated (time shifted) item.

Disadvantage is that you store the same data twice.

Examples:
return the average value for last minute

```
avg(60)
```

will return the average value for a minute one day ago (timeshifted value)

```
avg(60,86400)
```

Doc is your friend: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/appendix/triggers/functions

Comment: Sorry, but its something different. It will be one value which is average for that day. Its not a shift, its a period for apply avg